# Erro ao fazer requisição Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Quando tento fazer um requisição **ajax** usando o comando `$.post` do jQuery aparece um erro no netWork do chrome alguém sabe o que pode ser esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**: estou usando o framework codeigniter

```
$.post('/pages/entradaprodutos/carregar_notasfiscais',{
        codigo:$("#fornecedores").val()
        },function(resposta){
                console.log(resposta) 
         });
```

Comment: Isso não é um erro, é um aviso... Pode compartilhar a chamada Ajax para analisarmos?

Comment: Pronto, editei a pergunta...

Comment: Qual a response?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que pesquisei, isso pode ser causado por algo que está interceptando o seu request, e enviando um request vazio.

Possivelmente um bloqueador de propagandas (como o AdBlock), como indicado nesta resposta do SOEN:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21179105/195417

**Sugestão:** tenta instalar o [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) para ver como está ficando o request sendo feito, pois deve haver algo interceptando o request... depois de fazer isso, tente verificar em outros navegadores, e ver como os requests ficam em cada um dos navegadores... assim poderá isolar o problema cada vez mais.

**EDIT** Mais sugestões baseadas no SOEN:

- Iniciar o chrome com `--disable-extensions` na linha de comando (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21400449/195417)
- Verificar se o request não está sendo feito a outro domínio
- Recurso está sendo carregado do cache do browser (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21272049/195417)... e.g. por falta de conectividade ao servidor, o browser pega um recurso do cache, sem atualmente fazer o request.

Comment: putz, que coincidência kkkk

Comment: Mas eu não tenho nenhuma extensão chamada AdBlock no meu navegador

Comment: e também esse erro só da de vez em quando.. talvez pode ser algum processo que está sendo rodado no navegador porque o erro só da de vez em quando

Comment: @PauloRoberto , sim eu já tinha visto a pergunta do soen mas não resolveu me problema aí eu peguei a imagem deles para não precisar mostrar minha url mas a final o erro é mesmo

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Sem a possibilidade de reproduzir o problema, só posso ajudar com a pesquisa... editei a resposta... se não for nada disso, ai quando você resolver, por favor poste a solução como uma resposta, de forma a ajudar outros que passem pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo OK, pode deixar.

Answer (score 1):

**Obs:** Há uma pergunta extremamente parecida com a sua [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21177387/2319589), a imagem é idêntica.

## Resposta Traduzida do SOEN

O recurso poderia estar sendo bloqueado por uma extensão (AdBlock, etc..)

A mensagem está aí porque a requisição para resgatar este recurso, nunca foi feita, por isso os headers sendo apresentados não são reais.

## [Referência(resposta no SOEN)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21179105/2319589)

Comment: Sim eu já vi está pergunta mas eu não tenho nenhuma extensão AdBlock instalada no meu browser

Comment: há e sim eu já tinha visto a pergunta do soen mas não resolveu me problema aí eu peguei a imagem deles para não precisar mostrar minha url mas a final o erro é mesmo

Comment: nos comentários da resposta eu achei o seguinte: "Tente digitar `chrome://net-internals`, executar seu código, depois volte a tela do `chrome://net-internals` e use o campo de texto para procurar o evento relacionado à sua requisição (partes da url), então clique no evento e veja se as informações te ajudam.